# change datatype of columns in R

Tags: r

Quite new to R and need some expert advise.
I have a dataset that has around 21 columns that are categorical and continous.
Below is some example:
[test credit data]

The categorical variable columns such as Gender, Academic Qualification, Marial, Age,.. are of class integers. I want to convert them to factor Datatype. Trying to o something like:

```
    factorvar=c("Gender","Academic_Qualification","Marital","Repayment_Status_Jan", 
          "Repayment_Status_Feb",   "Repayment_Status_March",   
          "Repayment_Status_April", "Repayment_Status_May", 
          "Repayment_Status_June","agebin")    
for(factor_var in names(Traincreddata)%in%factorvar){
  Traincreddata[factor_var]=as.factor(Traincreddata$factor_var)
  }
```

However, I get an error:
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, factor_var, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 items, need 22500

I understand what the error is, but I am not sure how to fix this. I could do all these variables one-by-one but looking for a shorter code.

Thank you
Harish

Comment: This `names(Traincreddata)%in%factorvar` returns a *logical vector*, not a vector of names.

Answer (score 0):

`names(Traincreddata)%in%factorvar)` will give you a true/false value. To get the actual names, use `names(Traincreddata)[names(Traincreddata)%in%factorvar)]`

In any case, you can use lapply instead of for loop

```
names <- names(Traincreddata)[names(Traincreddata)%in%factorvar)] 
Traincreddata[,names] <- lapply(Traincreddata[,names] , factor)
```